# Kibana shorten column name in data table

Tags: kibana, kibana-4

Is it possible to *beautify* this data table using advanced JSON or something?

Currently, I'm getting this back:
[image: My Kibana UI]

Ideally, I'd like to get rid of everything else, except date, which is `yyyy-MM-dd`.

I've added this JSON to Advanced JSON Input:

```
{
  "format" : "yyyy-MM-dd"
}
```

It does work in backend side, results are brought back in this format. However - Kibana still displays them in its own manner.

Elasticsearch version - 2.0

Kibana version - 4.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can change the data format with kibana in the menu of the index. You go to the camp and select type date and the format. They allow multiple diferents format. As yyyy-mmmm that even display the name of the month.

EDIT:

The best option to dont change all the date is perhaps duplicate the date and only change the new data with the new format.

PD: is awesome that with scripted field you can do doc['time].value and you can not change the type of the new field but Kibana change the value to miliseconds.

Comment: I know this, however it's going to change this globally and I don't want it.

Comment: You can create then an new scripted field and only use the new field to beauty the representation.

Comment: Could you help with that? I've never used scripting in ES.

Comment: I think that perhaps a better solution is duplicate the camp date and have one with the format change in kibana and other to the other options. With scripted camp nowadays you can not select the type as an date.

Comment: That does make sense. Could you update your answer with that? I'll accept it.